# ROS2 detect color and move towards it

Tags: python, ros2

I am trying to update my script, to get the Turtlebot to find a certain color in the room and go to it. Right now my script finds the wall and avoids it.

def subscriber_callback(self, msg : LaserScan, move_cmd = Twist()):
#display distances

```
    '''GAZEBO VALUES FOR msg.ranges: 0, 360
    REAL TIME VALUES FOR msg.ranges: 0, 250'''

    front_left_val= msg.ranges[340:359]
    front_right_val= msg.ranges[0:20]
    front_vals = list([front_left_val, front_right_val])
    print(f'front left val: {front_left_val}')
    print(f'front right val: {front_right_val}')

    if min(front_right_val) < 0.8 and min(front_left_val) > min(front_right_val):
        self.turn_right()
        time.sleep(6)
    elif min(front_right_val) < 0.8:
        self.turn_left()
        time.sleep(6)
    else:
        self.move_forward()
```

Comment: You cannot do that using just range data! [LaserScan msgs](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) give you information that normally a LIDAR will provide you.

In order to achieve that you will need a different callback that uses [Image msgs](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) or [Pointcloud2 msgs](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html).